# how to rename your drive?

Tags: drive, rename

I want to rename my drive located at /media/Lenovo Drive to /media/LenovoDrive so that ndk white space problem can be resolved ...please give me your suggestion....I am using ubuntu

Comment: Did you create your own folder in /media for that mount?  If you did, all you should have to do is to unmount it first, rename the folder, then update `/etc/fstab` to the new folder name then remount the drive by using `mount -a` or `sudo mount -a`.

Answer (score 7):

## GUI ways

You can use the following GUI tools to change filesystem label.

### GNOME Disks (`gnome-disks`, in older versions of ubuntu `gnome-disk-utility`)

1. Open it (in MATE - *Applications -> Accessories -> Disks*).
2. Select partition and unmount [image: umount] (it is tooltip is *Unmount selected partition*)
3. Click on gears icon [image: gears icon] (it is tooltip is *Additional partition options*)
4. Then select *Edit Filesystem* drop-down menu

[image: Edit Filesystem menu]

1. Set filesystem label in opened window and click *Change*:

[image: Filesystem Label]

### Gparted (`gparted-pkexec`)

1. Open it (in MATE - *System -> Administration -> GParted*).
2. Select proper disk in top right drop-down menu:

[image: disk selection]

3. Select partition in list below

[image: select partition]

4. In *Partition* menu click *Label File System*, change *Label*

   [image: label FS]
5. Click *OK*
6. Confirm operation by clicking on [image] (tooltip is *Apply All Operations*).

Answer (score 3):

Use tune2fs to change your volume label (suppose the volume is sdb1)

```
sudo tune2fs -L LenovoDrive /dev/sdb1
```

Note that current Ubuntus actually mount at /media/username/xxx, so
you must be running an old copy.  Consider updating, 18.04 has just been released.

Comment: This works for partitions with ext2, ext3 and ext4 file systems. But you need another tool for FAT32 and yet other tools for other file systems. `gparted` can do it for several file systems (if you have a graphical desktop environment).

Answer (score 0):

1. Open disks.
2. Select the partition of your choice in the Volume section
3. Click Edit Filesystem (Label)
4. Enter a name in the field and click on Apply to validate.

Comment: Hello and welcome to AU.  Could you specify what you mean 'Open disks'?  What program are you supposed to do that?

Comment: Hello. Open "Disks" on ubuntu. The program is "Disks"